# My variables won't count because the compiler thinks they may not be spawned

Tags: java, jgrasp

I'm making a program for doing sin, cos, tan function and am in progress

However, because I used an if-else statement, it thinks that my variable (stepc) may not be initialized.
Since trig graphs are repetitive, I'm trying to make all graphs under the range of 0 to 360.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Trigonometry
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        double answer;
        double x;
        double stepa;
        double stepb;
        double stepc;
        double stepd;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number");  
        x = scanner.nextDouble(); 

        stepa = Math.abs(x);

        stepb = stepa / 360 ;

        if(stepb > 1)                   // <-- my functions for step c
        {
            while (stepb>1)
            {
                stepc = stepb - 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stepc=stepb;
        }

        stepd=stepc*360;            // <--  won't consider step c 

        System.out.println( stepc );
    }
}
```

```
----jGRASP exec: javac -g Trigonometry.javaenter code here

Trigonometry.java:34: variable stepc might not have been initialized
stepd=stepc*360;
^
1 error

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize stepc to some default value when you define it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a value to it before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving values to your step[abcd] variables when you initialize them?

Also, if stepb > 1, your code, as written, will never terminate.  Do you see why?

Comment: Sir, The values people input are values to be assigned to the steps

Comment: @user2999870 : sure, but if you declare double stepa = 0.0;, the later assignment operation will overwrite the zero.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have noted, use:

```
    double answer;
    double x;
    double stepa;
    double stepb;
    double stepc = 0;
    double stepd;
```

edit: no harm in assigning values to the other variables too.

also, be aware that this loop is probably running infinitely:

```
        while (stepb>1)
        {
            stepc = stepb - 1;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you friend, would giving it a value overwrite the values people input into it?

Comment: Because you give the variable a value at it's initialization, it won't override anything. (and they can still get a new value, because they are not `final`).